# x.org customisation works in GDM but not in user session

Tags: xorg, mouse

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, and I have made a customisation in my /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d folder to enable wheel emulation on my mouse. The wheel emulation works as expected in GDM, but when I start my session the emulation stops.

I've checked that I don't have a ~/.xinputrc or anything of the kind. What else should I look for that would be overriding the behaviour of my mouse when I log in?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the Gnome Setting Daemon Mouse plugin is overriding the settings from xorg. There is a bug filed about this behaviour https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1363669

The workaround is to disable the mouse plugin:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.mouse active false
```